# How to wrap the output of checkboxGroupInput?

Tags: css, r, shiny

How to modify the following code so that the options of 'checkboxGroupInput' wrap within 'width: 200px'?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style("
      .custom-wrap {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 200px;
      }
      "
  ),
  div(class = "custom-wrap",checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                                    c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                      "Transmission" = "am",
                                      "Gears" = "gear")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Delete `div` and try by `checkboxGroupInput`'s id (#variable in your case).

Comment: @PawełChabros Can you please share any link of used case?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all children of the `checkboxGroupInput` use this selector `#variable *`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style("
      #variable * {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 200px;
      }
      "
  ),
  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                     c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                       "Transmission" = "am",
                       "Gears" = "gear")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks.. It solved a part of my problem..  BTW it requires only "display: flex;"